# I am getting an empty array as result from database

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, database, backend

I am creating a sign up page and getting all the information from user using form but everything is working fine except the part where I am checking if the user exists or not

```
router.post("/test", async(req, res) => {
  let username = req.body.user;
  await con.query(checkUser, [username], (err, result) => {
    if (err) throw err;
    else if (result.length > 0) {
      console.log(result)
      res.send("User found")
    } else {
      console.log(result)
      res.send("User not found")
      console.log(username)
    }
  })
})
```

```
checkUser = "SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `username` = (?)";
```

I created separate post router to check the bug and the problem is my first else part is not working every time **I get result as an empty array weather the user exists or not** and res user not found, also **when I console the username I got it as undefined**

I test the sql separately in the admin page of mysql and its working perfectly am getting result

Comment: If you're using `mysql-promise`, then you can't use the callback argument to `con.query()`. If you're not, you shouldn't be using `await`.

Comment: @Barmar I tried using it without promise the result is still same

Comment: If `console.log(username)` says undefined, the problem has nothing to do with MySQL. The problem is with your body parsing.

Answer (score 0):

Dont use callback here to get your result instead do something like

let result = await conn.query(...);

And wrap the whole code in try catch to catch the errors.

Comment: Why would that make a difference?